# Understanding of Simple Present tense

Tags: present-tense

Can you please let me know which sentence is correct?

Supreme Court concerns on India sex ratio.

Or

Supreme Court concern on India sex ratio.

As I have watched in news that they have not appended "s" to verb, however I thought that it is required as it is in Simple present tense.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because it seeks to analyse the (non-existent) "grammar" of newspaper headlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Supreme Court concern on India sex ratio*

The above sentence is correct.

This is because in this case the word ***concern*** is being used as a noun. This is probably done to shorten the sentence for use as a headline.

If the same were to be used as a verb, the sentence would sound like:

*The Supreme Court concerns itself with India's sex ratio.*

EDIT:

As CopperKettle has suggested, a better usage of the word 'concern' as a verb in this context would be:

*The Supreme Court is concerned with India's sex ratio.*

Comment: +1, but "concerns itself with" is a bit unidiomatic for the purpose. It's usually "is concerned about"

Comment: I'm trying to use the same word the OP has in order to demonstrate the difference. But, the usage you have suggested indeed sounds better.

Comment: Thanks both of you....  then "The Supreme Court is concerned with India's sex ratio" is in Passive voice right or in active only. Please let me know

Comment: Both are active.

Comment: The fact whether 'concern' can be used in the passive voice is a question in itself.

Comment: could you please give an example?

Comment: *India's sex ratio concerns the Supreme Court.*

Comment: Akash, as here CopperKettle used "concerned" instead of "concern" that is why i am confused. Sorry for asking, however i want to clarify my doubts that is why.. Or he used "concerned" as an adjective instead of verb.

Comment: -1 The first line in this answer is ***not*** a "sentence" at all - it's just a noun phrase, as often used in *headlines* (with non-standard/non-existent grammar).

Comment: In case you havent noticed, this is what I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than conjecture whether your examples are headlines, let me just say that neither one is a sentence. Period. So one cannot determine what wording would be better.

Neither is even close to being correct grammatically, so it cannot be parsed for semantics.